# Get instagram picture

Tags: php, api, photo, instagram

Does anybody know how to retrieve and Instagram picture?
I mean like users fill in the link on my site of the picture e.g.http://instagram.com/p/RTqrWXkEme/ (does not exist just example) and then I show them the picture only

I'm sure this works via Instagram's API but I have no idea how..

Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for this [API endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect).

Given your example it would be:

```
http://instagr.am/p/RTqrWXkEme/media/?size=t
```

**Edit:** As the original photo is just an example here is a real picture:

```
https://instagr.am/p/ay2uOUwYJv/media/?size=t
```

[image: Instagram Picture]

Oh and btw you can control the size of the image:

> One of t (thumbnail), m (medium), l (large). Defaults to m.

```
https://instagr.am/p/ay2uOUwYJv/media/
```

[image: Instagram Picture]

```
https://instagr.am/p/ay2uOUwYJv/media/?size=l
```

[image: Instagram Picture]

Comment: That's because the original image isn't working, the API is still the same. How about submitting an edit proposal yourself, or at least – if you want me to do something – having a friendly tone.